# Debugging "unable to connect to sendmail server"

Tags: networking, debugging, sendmail, smtp

In a corporate environment, we have a mail server which has only ports 25/tcp and 587/tcp available.

When we use Perl Scripts (using HTML::Mail) to send hundreds of legitimate mails, it occasional fails with "Failed to connect to mail server".

We feel that the heavy load on the sendmail server is making it reject the connection, or maybe not even respond to the initial request.

Now, the team which owns the mail server is not cooperative and demands proof of the server rejecting the connection.

**Question : What information can be collected from client side in case of failure, assuming that issue is on server side ? How to prove that the issue is on server side, provided that is indeed the case ?**

[[ I am not sure if this question is valid here ; I can not ask for help in resolving the issue when the issue itself is not clear ; I am asking for a short list of tips and tricks to help Debug this issue ; I would even be open to inputs on workarounds ]]

Comment: Could you provide link to page of the module at cpan.org?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip , hmmm , HTML::Mail seems to be obsolete ; http://code.activestate.com/ppm/HTML-Mail/ has a web-link to http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Mail/ , but that says that this module cannot be found. POD on the local Installation says that it internally uses MIME::Lite , which again discourages the usage , & recommends the usage of Email::MIME or MIME::Entity or Etc. I will ask the owners of the Mail Script to update it.

Comment: 1) Do you reuse SMTP connection to send many messages? 2) Do you limit number of messages submitted per second? (Do not send as fast as YOU can) => Both measures should make you encounter the problem rarely. Other fixes I can suggest would be "sendmail specific" and require sendmail admins cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is for the sendmail team to look at their "/etc/mail/sendmail.mc" file:

```
dnl #
dnl # The following limits the number of processes sendmail can fork to accept 
dnl # incoming messages or process its message queues to 20.) sendmail refuses 
dnl # to accept connections once it has reached its quota of child processes.
dnl #
dnl define(`confMAX_DAEMON_CHILDREN', `20')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Limits the number of new connections per second. This caps the overhead 
dnl # incurred due to forking new sendmail processes. May be useful against 
dnl # DoS attacks or barrages of spam. (As mentioned below, a per-IP address 
dnl # limit would be useful but is not available as an option at this writing.)
dnl #
dnl define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_THROTTLE', `3')dnl

(Treat "dnl" as a comment leadin string.)
```

If you are just blasting the emails out, you probably should throttle them.

Comment: +1 , for pointing out what the sendmail team should check, but the problem is that the sendmail team in uncooperative and wants proof that there is no fault in client or network. My question is more about what can be captured on client side to prove this.

Comment: Log exact time and exact errors.  It should help sendmail team to search sendmail logs for specific troubles.

Answer (score 1):

Log error messages and EXACT time when problems occur. It should help sendmail admins to pinpoint problems in the log files.

With mass mailing you should:
a) reuse SMTP connection to send many emails (e.g. 50)
b) limit number of messages submitted per second (e.g. 20-50)

Other measures I could suggest would be sendmail specific and require cooperation of sendmail admins.

Comment: +1 , for client side suggestions. Actually, we already have the tracking in log files and DB, when-ever mail fails ; we do have the timestamps and error messages. We retry 5 times after a random interval (between 60 seconds & 120 seconds) and all failures are listed. Mails are sent by many independent processes, and each process sends only one mall, hence there is no easy way to limit mails per second, but anyway there are not many mails, probably 5 per minute. Other users across the organization might be sending more.

Comment: Could you tell something more about the environment?  e.g. Can you set up your own mail server to relay mails to "corporate smtp server"?  Can you use "sendmail" program (with custom path) instead of SMTP?

Comment: Again, that is one of the "heavier" solutions we are considering : have a relay server which will retry sending the mail off-line in batches, but the main process can terminate after sending the single mail to the new relay server.